# Accessing the two treasure chests that are under the villa?

Tags: assassins-creed-2

In the area of the Villa there are two treasure chests indicated on the map, as so:

[image: Cropped Assassins Creed 2 screenshot - minimap near villa]

This screenshot was taken while I was on the stairs to the underground sanctuary, and the map items are lit up, which usually indicates they're at the same elevation as myself and so I presume they must be underground? Having looked, they don't seem to be in the building, or on the roof, so I'm pretty sure they must be under there somewhere.

I'm sure it's completely unnecessary to get them, but I tried looking for them and couldn't find them, and now I'm annoyed. So, how do I get to them?

Comment: Have you tried exploring the mine/well just outside the villa? There are some treasure chests in there, but you might need to repair them first to open them up, I can't remember for sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that those two are located under the front door pavement. You can get there via the well that is located on the left when you exit the villa from the front door.

DMA57361 provides images itself (from comms):

## Going to the well:

[image]

## The puzzle to the chest

[image]

## And there you are

[image]

Comment: Yup, this is it. I've just tried it out, [here's](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eIcF4.jpg) the well, [there's](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Bd7a1.jpg) the view from the bottom, and finally [the chests are mine](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NKAGA.jpg)! Thanks!

Comment: Cool, I have embedded the images in the answer then. Makes a better answer

Answer (score 1):

These are in the mine.   This area is accessed from outside the town, at the base of the hillside just behind the villa - the entrance is obvious, but sealed.  You'll unlock it once you make that upgrade to the town.

Comment: Having now found these chests (see comments on M'vy's answer) I do remember having visited the mine already - it's pretty much the same on the inside (a small climbing puzzle) so very similar, but these specific two chests are inside the well, not the mine.

Comment: Oh, oops, there's my stupid memory, I found the well ones instantly so I didn't think they were hard (you do have to repair it but I think it's the very first thing I did).  I do remember seeing the mine ones for the longest time in just this manner though, so I'll leave the answer because somebody else might miss those exactly like this.